# Elasticsearch REST High Level Client combine query builders

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to create something like an advanced search using ES REST High Level Client (Java).
First, I have a search keyword that searches for all fields.
I use `QueryStringQueryBuilder` for this.

```
SearchSourceBuilder ticketInfoSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
ticketInfoSourceBuilder.from(pageable.getOffset());
ticketInfoSourceBuilder.size(pageable.getPageSize());
ticketInfoSourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder(sortField).order(sortOrder));
ticketInfoSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("ABC1234"));
```

Now, I need to add some more filters using `TermsQueryBuilder`.

Is it possible to combine the two query builders?

I would like to add the following filters:

```
"terms" : { "ticket.inquiryType" : ["INQTYP01", "INQTYP06"]}
"terms" : { "ticket.status" : ["NEW", "CLOSED"]}
"terms" : { "ticket.ownership" : ["OWNED", "OTHER_OWNER"]}
```

Is it possible to combine both query builders, to achieve something like an advance search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a `bool` query like this:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
   .must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("ABC1234"))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("ticket.inquiryType", "INQTYP01", "INQTYP06"))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("ticket.status", "NEW", "CLOSED"))
   .filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("ticket.ownership", "OWNED", "OTHER_OWNER"));
ticketInfoSourceBuilder.query(query);
```

Comment: Good one!
For term queries, you can pass a  Set instead of mentioning all the strings